# Weird behavior of if(true) on JavaScript scope..?

Tags: javascript, scope, constants, var, let

So I was testing scope of JavsScript (var, let, and const), and I found a weird behavior that I couldn't really understand.

```
var write = document.getElementById('demo');

function test() {
    var m = 'hello';
}

test();

write.innerHTML = m;
//This doesn't work
```

In above case, JS cannot accesses **var m** declared locally from global scope.

```
var write = document.getElementById('demo');

if(true) {
    var m = 'hello';
}

write.innerHTML = m;
//This works
```

In above case, JS accesses **var m** declared locally from global scope.

Can someone explain why that is..?

Comment: `var ` has functional scope not a block scope.

Comment: As above. You want to use `let` for block scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Use ‘let’ and the second won’t work either -block scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the first case**, `var` declaration is scoped at function level and thus its limited to `function test`

In the **second case**, if scope is block scope and hence `var` declaration escapes into the global scope due to `Hoisting`

Thus in the first case you can't use `m` outside function test but you can do so in the second case.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Also `var` has function level scope

```js
var write = document.getElementById('demo');
var m; // m will be undefined here, declared but not initialized
if (true) {
  m = 'hello'; // m is initialized her
}

write.innerHTML = m;
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```